# Automated Drive Formatting?

Tags: c++, batch-file, hard-drive

Is there an easy way to format several drives programmatically? We have a batch file (below) that we use to format thumb drives but we are required to press enter every time a drive is successfully formatted. I'm assuming this is a safeguard to prevent evil-doers from creating drive formatting viruses. In any case, I was thinking of automating this using C++ but haven't been able to find any good resources. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
start for %%i in (e:, f:, g:, h:, i:, j:, k:, l:, m:, n:, o:, p:, q:, r:, s:, t:, u:, v:)
do format %%i /FS:fat32 /x /q /v:
```

Comment: If you are using `winapi` you should checkout the `CreateProcess`, `CreatePipe`, `SetStdHandle`, `WriteFile`, `ReadFile` and similar functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this on WinXP machines you should be able to add `/Y` to format without user interaction. Older versions of DOS used the `/AUTOTEST` switch. I know `/AUTOTEST` could not be combined with `/Q`, but I'm not sure if `/Y` has the same requirement or not. Should be easy enough for you to test and find out.

Comment: We're using win7 machines and /y worked just fine. Thank you so much!